Two HTTPS applications on the same host
Is it possible to run to HTTPS applications on the same host?
For example:

Python FastAPI Back-End on port 8000 using HTTPS.

JS React Front-End on port 4000 using HTTPS.


Will it work without a TLS proxy?
I read a blog that a host can have only one certificate and only one application can use HTTPS.

Does this answer your question? What is a Reverse Proxy?

Yes you can run multiple https services on the same host.
"I have read that one host can have only one certificate" - this has never been true. I don't know where you read this. +12 years ago you could only have one certificate per IP address and port combination (this constraint was removed by SNI). By convention, webservers are logically divided into separate bundles of functionality commonly known as virtual hosts - and by convention you would only have 0 or 1 certificates per virtual host.
Even before the advent of SNI you could easily aggregate multiple backends on a single IP address + port using a reverse proxy by associating different paths with different backends.
However almost all application servers REALLY SUCK at HTTP/HTTPS (e.g.  supporting virtual hosts). Further, exposing an application server directly to the network is almost always bad for performance, security and capacity. There's no good reason to NOT use a lightweight proxy (nginx, haproxy, lighttpd....) in front of such a service.


You can run multiple application over https, if they are running on different ports. You must have a domain name to configure SSL certificate, as you can't serve site with https with IP address.


https://example.com:8000
https://example.com:4000


If you want to serve both sites with different URLs and common port (443) like https://one.example.com and https://two.example.com, then you need to setup a frontend proxy server like Apache or Nginx. This works for me: https://tecadmin.net/apache-frontend-proxy-nodejs/


You can serve TLS using IP.
